# React-native Firebase Auth setState in onAuthStateChanged got TypeError: this.setState is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am starting with react-native and trying to fetch firebase user data by using onAuthStateChanged.

I tried to do `bind` `this` but still I have no clue about it.

this is my constructor

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    isUid: '',
      isProvider:'',

      isPhoneNumber:'', 
    };
```

and this is my onAuthStateChange in componentDidMount

```
componentDidMount() { 
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
    if (user) {
      user.providerData.forEach(function (profile) {

        this.setState({isProvider: profile.providerId}, console.log(isProvider)).bind(this); 
        this.setState({isPhoneNumber: profile.phoneNumber}, console.log(isPhoneNumber)).bind(this);
        this.setState({isUid: user.uid}, console.log(isUid)).bind(this);
});
} else {
  console.log('no user');
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're in the `onAuthStateChanged` callback, `this` has a different meaning from outside of that.

The simplest fix is to use fat arrow notation, which maintains the meaning of `this`:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
      user.providerData.forEach(function (profile) {
        this.setState({isProvider: profile.providerId}, console.log(isProvider)).bind(this); 
        this.setState({isPhoneNumber: profile.phoneNumber}, console.log(isPhoneNumber)).bind(this);
        this.setState({isUid: user.uid}, console.log(isUid)).bind(this);
      });
    } else {
      console.log('no user');
    }
}
```

Comment: I got `[Unhandled promise rejection: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: isProvider]` it seems like it still didnt set the state.

Comment: That's a different error. It sounds like `isProvider` is not in scope when you try to use it, but based on the code you shared I can't say why that is. The original error is caused by what I explain in my answer though, which is why that error disappeared when you applied the change I point out.